# Flutter/Dart: Text in Widget changes based on which Screen called it?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, static, parameter-passing

I've got a stateful widget that records audio. It's used on two different screens. I'd like the text on its button to be based upon the screen it's called from. IE: If it's called from one screen the text is "Record" but if it's called from another screen the text is "Try it".

So I passed a parameter to it with the name of the screen that calls it. Then I tried to use a variable with a conditional. But the parameter isn't available and is underlined red. Android Studio tells me "only static members can be accessed in initializers".

So how do I access the "whichscreen" parameter so that I can use it in a variable/conditional?

Here's the code:

```
class SpeakRecorder extends StatefulWidget {
  final String whichscreen;

   SpeakRecorder({
      this.whichscreen
   })
     
  String screenchoice = (whichscreen == "recordscreen") ? "Record" : "Try it";
```

...

And here's the widget which needs the record button text choice;

```
 Widget _buildText(RecordingStatus status) {
    var text = "";
    switch (_currentStatus) {
      case RecordingStatus.Initialized:
        {
          text = screenchoice;
          break;
        }
      case RecordingStatus.Recording:
        {
          text = 'Pause';
          break;
        }
      case RecordingStatus.Paused:
        {
          text = 'Resume';
          break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
    return Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be declaring this variable/conditional somewhere else? Or is there a better approach I should be taking?

Comment: in the state class you can access properties from the corresponding widget over [`widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html), so try `widget.whichscreen`.

Comment: Amazing! The declaration worked when I put it within the _buildText widget itself. Then I was able to call widget.whichscreen. So I'm marking this as solved. But how do I give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `State` and the `StatefulWidget` are 2 different classes, but you can access the corresponding `StatefulWidget` from within a `State` by using [`State.widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html):

```dart
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  final String prop;
  // ...
}

class ExampleState extends State<ExampleWidget>{
  // here you can get the prop of the corresponding widget with widget.prop  
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text(widget.prop);
  }

  //...
}
```